# phpMyAdmin Fatal error: Allowed memory size

Tags: php, mysql, memory, phpmyadmin, myisam

I'm using Laravel on localhost for a project. There is a function (for searching posts) that needs a table to be in MyISAM. So I went to my table 'posts' and select MyISAM in the 'Operations' panel.

But after that I have this error :

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2102513 bytes) in /Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/index.php on line 16" and I cannot access to any page of my PhpMyAdmin. I'm pretty worried.

I tried to search a solution, I increase the memory limit in my php.ini but it didn't change a thing... If you have any idea, I'll be very glad to read it !

Thanks ;)

Comment: In what way is laravel relevant to your question? In what way is the error message unclear?

Answer (score 2):

I've run into a similar problem before with phpMyAdmin. I'm assuming that this only happens when you click on one specific table? Did you forget to put indexes on that table or remove the primary key?

If PMA cannot find a primary key for a table instead of generating simple links like:

```
index.php?action=delete&pk=1
```

it will use *every single column* like:

```
index.php?action=delete&col1=foo&col2=bar&col3=baz&col4=...
```

which can easily exhaust PHP's memory limit if there's a lot of data stored in the table.

If you have another program to admin you mySQL DBs like MySQL Workbench, or HeidiSQL use that to fix the Primary Key on the table. If you don't, you're going to have to start cranking up PHP's memory limit until you can load that table in PMA. Just remember to turn it back down once you've fixed it.

Comment: Very interesting. `If you have another program to admin you mySQL DBs` - everyone who uses a database should know how to (at the very least as a last resort) open a terminal window, type `mysql` and execute sql commands to correct that kind of situation. If this answer is "the answer", reliance on phpMyAdmin, or any tool that puts itself between the developer and the actual database, is "the problem" to address IMO - the rest is just symptoms. +1.